# Xcode : warning: directory not found for option

Tags: xcode, ios5, linker, linker-errors

```
Ld /Users/pwang/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/socketiohldwxnslzhlnjtgihgewdwavpjpb/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/socketio.app/socketio normal armv7
cd /Users/pwang/Desktop/saturngod-Socket.io-with-iOS-be51414
setenv IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 4.3
setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch armv7 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.1.sdk -L/Users/pwang/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/socketio-hldwxnslzhlnjtgihgewdwavpjpb/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -L/Users/pwang/Desktop/saturngod-Socket.io-with-iOS-be51414/socketio/simulator -L/Users/pwang/Desktop/saturngod-Socket.io-with-iOS-be51414/socketio/device -F/Users/pwang/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/socketio-hldwxnslzhlnjtgihgewdwavpjpb/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -F/Users/pwang/Desktop/saturngod-Socket.io-with-iOS-be51414/socketio -filelist   /Users/pwang/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/socketio-hldwxnslzhlnjtgihgewdwavpjpb/Build/Intermediates/socketio.build/Debug-iphoneos/socketio.build/Objects-normal/armv7/socketio.LinkFileList -dead_strip -lz -licucore -miphoneos-version-min=4.3 -framework MobileCoreServices -framework Foundation -lz -lxml2 -framework SystemConfiguration -framework CFNetwork -framework UIKit -framework CoreGraphics -o /Users/pwang/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/socketio-hldwxnslzhlnjtgihgewdwavpjpb/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/socketio.app/socketio

ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/pwang/Desktop/saturngod-Socket.io-with-iOS-be51414/socketio/simulator'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/pwang/Desktop/saturngod-Socket.io-with-iOS-be51414/socketio/device'
```

can you give me some clue to remove the warning,thank you.

Comment: Make sure you are opening the workspace too, not just the project file

Answer (score 158, accepted):

In **Target > Build Settings**:

Look for **Search Paths > Framework Search Paths**, delete all paths which you have been warned; then in **Library Search Paths**, delete all paths which you have been warned.

Comment: Worth clarifying that you have to select the _target_ rather than the project to see this.

Comment: Thanks, I hate warnings, this answer helps me!

Comment: Thanks, I had warning which is resolved by the answer. I deleted all the paths from my target which had this warning.

Comment: @jrturton Thank you! Finally! you deserve credit!

Answer (score 6):

I found this post looking for the same issue. However, my issue was that some framework was added then deleted and thus causing this error. After doing a clean on the project I was all good.

```
Product --> Clean
```