# How do i get rid of this warning

Tags: ios, restkit-0.20

I wanted to use RestKit in my project, and then found that i do not need it.

I've removed most of the installation steps, but I can't find where this warning is originating from

```
(null): Directory not found for option '-L/Users/dev1/Dev/IOSworkspace/myProject/RestKit/Build/Debug-iphonesimulator'
```

what do i need to do to remove that?

Comment: These links may help you 1.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11390918/warning-directory-not-found-for-option-l-users-saturngod-socket-io-with-ios   2.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13723074/directory-not-found-for-option-l-users-testflightsdk1-1  3.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8912551/xcode4-linker-error-directory-not-found-for-option

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look in your library header search paths in your project settings, there'll be a row there with the path above. Delete that row and the warning will go.

Answer (score 1):

go into build settings > there is search box on top & type a keyword (e.g. Restkit) & it will list down everything related to that which has entries. double click these entries and simply select & remove them. hope this helps